# What is the next result?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

The pound sign / number symbol / octotroph / hashtag represents a certain function. Given the examples below, can you figure out what that function is and what number should be where the `?` is?

```
   5 # 8 = 14 
  11 # 6 = 18 
   8 # 9 = 68
  12 # 8 =  ?
```

Comment: question mark or pound sign?

Comment: sorry, I am new. where is the pound sign ? You must find what does the question mark represent. (what is the result of 12 # 8)

Comment: aa...sorry. I misunderstood

Comment: +1 for using # instead of redefining + like so many annoying puzzles on Facebook seem to do.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

? could be

> 120

Explanation

> let $d(x)$ be the highest divisor of $x$ smaller than $x$
>  let $isprime(x)$ be $1$ if $x$ is prime or $0$ if $x$ is not prime
>  then $x$ # $ y = (x + y)*d(x)+isprime(x)$
>  $5$ # $8 = (5+8)*1+1 = 14$
>  $11$ # $6 =(11+6)*1+1 = 18$
>  $8$ # $9 = (8+9)*4 +0 = 68$
>  $12$ # $8= (12+8)*6+0= 120$

Comment: Probably there is more than one answer but your answer is correct. Well done!

Comment: A really good answer :)

Answer (score 6):

assuming operator `#` is symmetric, `?` could be equal to

> 59

Consider what would happen if we were to sort the operands:

```
5 #  8 = 14 
6 # 11 = 18 
8 #  9 = 68
8 # 12 =  ?
```

Assuming simple formula

> $$f(a, b) = (a-x)\cdot(b-y) + z$$

and solving it we get the following nice numbers: $x=11$, $y=-11$ and $z=128$ which implies the following definition of $\#$

> \begin{align}a\operatorname{\#}b &= \Big(\min(a,b)-11\Big)\Big(\max(a,b)+11\Big) + 128\\&=a\cdot b-11\cdot|a-b|+7\end{align}

$\ddot\smile$

Comment: I fixed a couple of errors in the formulae for you

Answer (score 4):

There are so many different possible solutions, due to only three examples, but I got

> ? = 21

The rule I used is

> Add the two numbers together.
>  If neither number is a perfect square, add 1.
>  If one of the numbers is a perfect square, multiply by one more than its square root.
>  There may be an additional rule for when both numbers are perfect squares, but that situation doesn't arise in the given examples.

Answer (score 2):

? is :

> 90

Rules for how I got there:

> if prime--sum numbers, add 1 (smallest denominator of LHS, trivial)   (5 + 8 + 1) = 14, (11 + 6 + 1) = 18   if both composite--multiply numbers, subtract largest denominator of LHS   (8 * 9 = 72, 72 - 4 = 68) --Solution (12 * 8 = 96, 96 - 6 = 90)